# Lucene: Searching for phrases in specific order

Tags: lucene

Using lucene I want to search for phrases (of multiple words) in specific order. I came across examples of spanquery for searching for single terms in specific order but that does not suit my requirements because I want to search for "phrases" occurring in specific order in a document when slop is not necessarily zero. So do we have any such feature in lucene? Or can we use spanquery to search for phrases in specific order?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [PhraseQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/index.html?org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html)?

Comment: I think phrasequery does not facilitate ordered search unless you set the slop to zero. Am I missing something? I need something like spanquery where you can search for terms in specific order but instead of single terms I want to search for multiple word phrases occurring in specific order.